# Unable to access swift file from static library to application target

Tags: objective-c, swift, static-libraries, bridging-header

I have workspace contains subprojects and one of the subprojects generates static lib which contains both ObjC and swift which is linked to main application project. I am unable to access a swift class from a static library in ObjC file in application target.

How can I access a swift class from the static library in ObjC file in application target?

Answer (score 2):

I figure it out. 
The issue was module-swift.h of subproject static library is generated in derivedData intermediate DerviedSource folder which is not known to main application target.
The issue resolved :)

Comment: so the  solution is add derivedData path for header search path in application target？

Comment: @YanLi Yes you have to specify the module-swift.h path in header search path

Comment: I have solved header file not found problem use your answer, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think, it is not possible. Xcode doesn't support Swift static libraries. You can read about it here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73900

Comment: Xcode 9 onwards support swift static library. My application uses it